# Replacing a linear softpot (ribbon sensor) with a regular potentiometer

Tags: voltage-divider, potentiometer, synthesizer

I'm a beginner with electronics.  I'm trying to replace a softpot on a cheap synthesizer with a regular potentiometer. As far as I can tell this component (pictured below) behaves just like a 10K pot; leads 1 and 2 are like the outer leads in a pot and always measure 10K, between 1 and 3 the resistance varies linearly depending on where you touch along the strip:

[image]

I soldered a ribbon cable to a small breakout board (pictured below), and it is at this point that things start to go wrong.

[image]

1. If I connect a 10K pot to the corresponding leads (before powering
   the synth on) The synth plays only the highest and sometimes second
   highest note as I sweep through the range
2. if I disconnect
   everything from the breakout board  the synth doesn't play, but then
   strangely if I touch my finger or an alligator clip to only terminal
   3 ( with no other part of the circuit connected)  it plays while the
   alligator clip is touching….

I have double checked for shorts  from the breakout board to the terminals on the synth circuit board using the continuity checker on my multimeter and it all looks fine.

So I'm looking for tips to help debug this, but also I'm very curious how (2) above could be happening

Comment: What's a "softpot"?

Comment: @Hearth maybe the proper term is "ribbon sensor"? It's something like this, though the component used here isn't made by them afaict: https://www.spectrasymbol.com/linear-position-sensors/soft-membrane-linear-pots-softpot I don't see any markings on the one I'm dealing with

Comment: You need to provide more info. Where exactly do you measure 10K? Where do you put your finger (for example) and what do you measure (& where)? Do you easure with a multimeter? What setting of the multimeter? etc. etc.

Comment: @StefanWyss I'm using a multimeter to measure resistance, yes (mine has one setting for that), and using the mode that beeps to check continuity where I say "I have double checked for shorts". The other stuff seems clear from the question to me, but maybe I'm misunderstanding. Lead 3 is connected to wiper, you move your finger along the strip and resistance varies between 1 and 3, and between 2 and 3, just like a regular pot

Comment: One thing that puzzles me about your description of the soft pot functionality: Is it true that it works if you bridge terminals 1 and 3 with your finger alone? The resistance of skin is multiple kilo Ohms, so this bridge is very weak!?

Comment: @StefanWyss what I found is that if I _simply_ touch terminal 3 the synth will turn on, i.e. the device is somehow detecting some change even though as far as I can tell I'm not completing any circuit, even through my body...

Comment: It seems that terminal 3 is an input with very high impedance. In this case your body acts as an antenna and picks-up noise, mostly from the AC power outlets nearby. You can see the same effect if you touch an oscilloscope probe tip.

Answer (score 0):

So uhhhh... it turned out it was actually one of the brand new alligator clips connecting the pot to my breakout board that was totally broken (I had even checked the range of the pot I was testing with using two of the three clips...). So, working as expected now.

Stefan Wyss explains what's probably happening in my second question:

> It seems that terminal 3 is an input with very high impedance. In this case your body acts as an antenna and picks-up noise, mostly from the AC power outlets nearby. You can see the same effect if you touch an oscilloscope probe tip.